# How to install qemu-kvm on kinetic when package not showing up in apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualization, qemu, lxd

I'm going around in circles trying to install qemu so I can run a lxd vm.

lxd gives me the error

> Error: Failed instance creation: Failed creating instance record:
> Instance type "virtual-machine" is not supported on this server: QEMU
> command not available for CPU architecture

I've done all the checks having turned on vm in my bios and everything checks out okay.

However I need the qemu command.

Having googled till my head hurts I keep coming back to the same suggestion which is to install the qemu-kvm package, and that's what I remember in the past, but on kinetic when I do a apt list there is no qemu-kvm package listed.

So I tried just doing apt install qemu-kvm to see if apt would do some magic and it did this

> Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-kvm'

Great it did some magic, but why was the package renamed?

Nope, that was some bad magic. It's not a replacement for the qemu-kvm package at all. So I uninstalled that package and all the packages it brought with it. And I am now back to square one.

Help!?

These are the qemu packages apt knows on my system

```
sudo apt list | grep qemu

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

aqemu/kinetic 0.9.2-3 amd64
golang-github-digitalocean-go-qemu-dev/kinetic,kinetic 0.0~git20220804.2002801-1 all
grub-firmware-qemu/kinetic-updates 2.06-2ubuntu12.1 amd64
ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms/kinetic,kinetic 1.0.0+git-20150424.a25a16d-0ubuntu4 all
ipxe-qemu/kinetic,kinetic 1.21.1+git-20220113.fbbdc3926-0ubuntu1 all
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu/kinetic-updates 8.6.0-0ubuntu3.1 amd64
nova-compute-qemu/kinetic-updates,kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,kinetic-security 3:26.1.0-0ubuntu1 all
oem-qemu-meta/kinetic,kinetic 20.04~ubuntu5 all
qemu-block-extra/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-efi-aarch64/kinetic,kinetic 2022.05-4 all
qemu-efi-arm/kinetic,kinetic 2022.05-4 all
qemu-efi/kinetic,kinetic 2022.05-4 all
qemu-guest-agent/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-arm/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-common/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-data/kinetic-updates,kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 all
qemu-system-gui/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-mips/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-misc/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-ppc/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-s390x/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-sparc/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-x86-xen/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-x86/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system-xen/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-system/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-user-binfmt/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-user-static/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-user/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-utils/kinetic-updates 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2.2 amd64
qemu-web-desktop/kinetic 22.04.22-1+ds1-1 amd64
qemubuilder/kinetic 0.89 amd64
sbuild-qemu/kinetic,kinetic 0.83.1ubuntu1 all
u-boot-qemu/kinetic-updates,kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,kinetic-security 2022.07+dfsg-1ubuntu4.3 all
```

And these are the repos I have enabled on my system

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 22.10 _Kinetic Kudu_ - Release amd64 (20221020)]/ kinetic main multiverse restricted universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
/etc/apt/sources.list:# newer versions of the distribution.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
/etc/apt/sources.list:## distribution.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list:## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
/etc/apt/sources.list:## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list:## security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
/etc/apt/sources.list:## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
/etc/apt/sources.list:## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
/etc/apt/sources.list:## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
/etc/apt/sources.list:## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security main restricted 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security universe 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:# This system was installed using small removable media
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list:# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
/etc/apt/sources.list:# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
/etc/apt/sources.list:# see the sources.list(5) manual.
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-kinetic.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-kinetic.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list:# deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ jammy main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ jammy main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-kinetic.list:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-kinetic.list.save:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-kinetic.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:# Uncomment these lines to try the beta version of the Steam launcher
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:# deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:# Uncomment these lines to try the beta version of the Steam launcher
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:# deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-gimp-kinetic.list:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-gimp-kinetic.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu/ kinetic main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-gimp-kinetic.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-gimp-kinetic.list.save:# deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-gimp-kinetic.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu/ kinetic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:# deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/ stable main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:
```

So please where do I go from here, how can I install qemu-kvm on kinetic?

**EDIT:**
I finally managed to work out what's going on.

The different naming from various points in this saga caused a lot of confusion for me, but I've finally managed to see through the fog.

So every google result just says install the qemu-kvm package but there is no qemu-kvm package. And lxd just says it can't find the qemu command.

So even though I initially relied on apt-get to perform some of it's magic and decided to install the qemu-system-x86 suggested by apt-get, it did not appear to be the solution for me because, the lxd daemon had already started after I finished building it from source, and it does not detect newly added modules, drivers, etc, plus lxc just says that it cannot find the qemu command, but there is no qemu command.

So my faith in apt-get magic wavered and I backed the qemu-system-x86 package out.

After a break from the problem, I tried again and saw that the daemon lxd was still running. So I stopped lxd, installed qemu-system-x86, started lxd and then all of a sudden lxc could find what it was looking for.

It would have helped me a lot if  the google results didn't make it sound like I should be looking for a package called qemu-kvm, but even then had I realized that lxd was running and stopped it before using apt-get the issue would have been resolved straight away.

It would also helped a lot if lxc didn't say it was looking for the **qemu command** as I took that to mean there should be a app named qemu somewhere, but ofc that command just does not exist in the qemu virtualization package.

**TL;DR**
So the solution was in fact *apt install qemu-system-x86*, which I originally did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install, update and use apt-file to locate /bin/kvm:

```
$ apt-file search bin/kvm |grep "kvm$"
qemu-system-x86: /usr/bin/kvm
```

So install the qemu-system-x86 package

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work, lxd still could not find qemu, so I uninstalled qemu-system-x86. It didn't help that all google results said to install the qemu-kvm package and lxd says it can't find qemu. So lots of name mangling causing confusion, but my problem turned out to be that the lxd was already running before I installed qemu-system-x86 so  lxc could not find qemu through the previous running lxd. I worked that out when I stopped lxd, re-installed qemu-system-x86 then restarted lxd, at which point lxc could then find qemu. Thanks for the reply though.